# Why the Sun does not shoot relativistic jets?

Tags: magnetic-fields, sun, relativistic-jets

I saw the features of the Sun [here](https://weatherboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Heliopedia.png) and it has almost everything include nanojets and CME but not relativistic jets. Isn't the Sun magnetically active so why isn't it capable of shooting out relativistic jets?

Comment: Do you have a better link to that source? Right now, you question isn't really understandable without the link, but it's a deep link to an image one someone else's server. That's a recipe for a question which won't make sense to anyone in a year.

Comment: I, for one, have no desire for our sun to be shooting relativistic jets anywhere near me...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Sun is able to eject relativistic particles (https://doi.org/10.1051/0004-6361/202243903, open access):

> The Sun accelerates electrons, protons, and ions to suprathermal
> energies in a variety of transient events, ranging from small flares
> to coronal mass ejections (CMEs). The processes governing the
> acceleration and propagation are relevant for astrophysical plasmas in
> general. In the solar case, the available diagnostics of non-thermal
> particles are particularly rich, including their electromagnetic
> emissions and measurements in space. In exceptional cases, particles
> are accelerated up to mildly relativistic energies, namely, GeV to
> tens of GeV for nucleons, and MeV for electrons.

Comment: These are not relativistic jets and therefore this doesn't address the question.